# How to access instance variable of other object of same class

Tags: ruby

This is a job interview problem. I'm supposed to create a data structure for a time in seconds and milliseconds, then create two `Time` objects, and then write a function that can return the difference between the two `Time`s. This is my code:

```
class Time
  def initialize (sec, milli_sec)
    @sec = sec
    @milli_sec = milli_sec
  end
  def difference(time_2)
    puts @sec.to_i*1000 + @milli_sec.to_i + time_2.@sec
  end
end

time_1 = Time.new('5','30')
time_2 = Time.new('6','40')
time_1.difference(time_2)
```

This is the error:

```
syntax error, unexpected tIVAR, expecting '('
```

I am having a problem accessing the `@sec`, `@milli_sec` variables of `time_2` passed as `time_1.difference(time_2)`. I think that the syntax is `time_2.@sec.to_i` or `time_2.#@sec.to_i`, but those return errors. `time_2.sec` returns uninitialized time, even though it looks like it's been initialized. I would like to know the solution to this problem.

Comment: Why not convert and store `int` values during `initialize`?

Answer (score 4):

`@sec` and `@milli_sec` are instance variables of your `Time` class.  This means that unless you do something else only the *instance* itself has access to them.  Other parts of your code can create an instance, but are only able to access the methods you specify.  The point of this is so that you can change the underlying implementation without affecting other parts of your code that are using this class.

There are a variety of ways to do this.  You could define the following two methods in your `Time` class:

```
def sec
  @sec
end

def milli_sec
  @milli_sec
end
```

These methods are public (by default) so you can now do this:

```
t = Time.new(1, 2)
puts t.sec # prints 1
puts t.milli_sec # prints 2
```

A more Ruby-ish way would be to add this line to the top of your class:

```
attr_reader :sec, :milli_sec
```

Doing this accomplishes the same thing as defining the two methods above.  You might also want to look at `attr_accessor`.

P.S. `Time` is a poor choice of class name for your own code as it's already defined by Ruby itself.

Comment: YOU beat me by seconds :( I wrote exactly the same thing. Grrrrrrr

Comment: Thank you Phillip, I was able to get it working by adding the two methods... but wasn't able to do it using: attr_reader :sec, :milli_sec ... I suppose that line would go above initialize? Is there ny other changes I would need to make (like remove the @ character or use the : character)?? Thank you!

Comment: @KameronWhite See https://gist.github.com/phallstrom/b6d593ebc39c6d66715d.  Especially lines 2 and end of line 10.

Answer (score 1):

In ruby, **every interface is a group of methods**. You can't just `obj.@var` to access instance variables since they are not methods thus not interfaces. If you want to expose instance variables, then create public methods to access them. `attr_reader` and `attr_accessor` are simply handy ways to create those methods.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final solution:

```
class Moment
def initialize (sec, milli_sec)
   @sec = sec
   @milli_sec = milli_sec
 end

def sec
   @sec
 end

def milli_sec
  @milli_sec
end

def difference(time_2)
 return ((@sec.to_i*1000 + @milli_sec.to_i) - (time_2.sec.to_i*1000 + time_2.milli_sec.to_i)).abs
 end
end

time_1 = Moment.new('1','300')
time_2 = Moment.new('11','20')

time_1.difference(time_2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
The same objective can be achieved in much lesser lines of code using approach as below:-

class MyTime

  attr_accessor :seconds, :milli_seconds

  def initialize(entity={})
    @seconds = entity['seconds']
    @milli_seconds = entity['milli_seconds']
  end

  def difference(obj)
    ms= ((@seconds.to_i*1000+@milli_seconds.to_i)-(obj.seconds.to_i*1000+obj.milli_seconds.to_i))
    secs = ms/1000 
    msecs = ms%1000
    return MyTime.new({'seconds'=> secs,
                        'milli_seconds'=> msecs})
  end

end

time_1 = MyTime.new({'seconds'=> '20',
                        'milli_seconds'=> '100'})
time_2 = MyTime.new({'seconds'=> '10',`enter code here`
                        'milli_seconds'=> '20'})
diff_Obj = time_1.difference(time_2)
puts "Difference is : #{diff_Obj.seconds} Seconds #{diff_Obj.milli_seconds} milliseconds"
```